# How do I find the other elements in a list given one of them?

Tags: python

Given one element in a list, what is the most efficient way that I can find the other elements?

(e.g. if a list is `l=["A","B","C","D"]` and you're given "B", it outputs "A", "C" and "D")?

Comment: What does "*other*"? exactly mean? Are you just looking for the *adjacent* elements? Or is it about removing B from the list? Given the same list A,B,C, what is the output if input is A or C? What if the list is A,B,C,D and the input is B, what then are the outputs? And "*efficient*" in terms of what, speed?

Comment: There are a few ways to interpret this question. What if there were two `"B"`s in the list?

Comment: What do you mean by "most efficient"? Fastest? Using the least amount of memory? Also, if there's more than one `"B"` in the list, would only one be removed from the original? Or all of them?

Comment: You can precompute a dict that givens an element returns the others.  O(n^2) to precompute and O(1) at run-time.  I don't know what efficient means and what your use case is.  Otherwise straight iteration perhaps like @Mark just suggested (which is what the precompute step is per element).  You could memorize the result and only pay the presume cost when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question-: **How do I find the other elements in a list given one of them?**

Think like.. **How can i remove that element in a list to get all other elements in a list  [Quite simple to approach now!!]**

**Some methods are:-**

```
def method1(test_list, item):
    #List Comprehension
    res = [i for i in test_list if i != item]
    return res

def method2(test_list,item):
    #Filter Function
    res = list(filter((item).__ne__, test_list))
    return res

def method3(test_list,item):
    #Remove Function
    c=test_list.count(item)
    for i in range(c):
        test_list.remove(item)
    return test_list
    
print(method1(["A","B","C","D"],"B"))
print(method2(["A","B","C","D"],"B"))
print(method3(["A","B","C","D"],"B"))
```

**Output:-**

```
['A', 'C', 'D']
['A', 'C', 'D']
['A', 'C', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to achieve this, you want to find the other elements excluding the value.
eg l1=[1,2,3,4,5]
2 to excluded
l1=[1,3,4,5]

```
# a list
l1 =["a","b","C","d"]
#input of the value to exclude 
jo = input()
l2=[]
for i in range(len(l1)):
        if l1[i]!=jo:
            l2.append(l1[i])
print(l2)
```

Comment: list is a built in data type..! don't initialize a list with a `list` name

Comment: you can directly append `l2.append(list[i])` no need of `a=list[i]`